# Make my computer shutdown on its own at a specified time. (Linux)

Tags: linux, shutdown

I would like to schedule my computer to shutdown on its own at 10pm. How can I make this possible ?

I heard that we can do this with [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Windows user here. I have the exact opposite problem :P

Comment: Edit crontab to schedule the `shutdown` command? For details see `man 5 crontab`. What did you try, what didn't work, what did you do to find out why it didn't work? (And maybe schedule a different command for getting used to it).

Answer (score 1):

As inferred by dirkt, the easiest way to do this is using crontab.  Because the command requires a high level of access, you need to run it as root.  One way of doing this is to edit /etc/crontab (for example sudo vi /etc/crontab) if you know how to use vi - and add the line:

> 00 22 * * * root  /sbin/shutdown -h now

Provided the system time is set correctly this will shut down the system at 10pm nightly.

Comment: I didn't give details on purpose, in case it's a "I'm too lazy to read the docs, let me just ask people on the internets" question. At least let him edit the question with what he tried ...